# Why isn't SQL Server using my non-clustered index and doing a clustered index scan?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014, query-performance

Here are my full tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblCrawlUrls](
    [cl_IdUrl] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [cl_CrawlNormalizedUrl] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [cl_RooSiteId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [cl_ExploreDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCrawlUrls_cl_ExploreDate]  DEFAULT (sysutcdatetime()),
    [cl_LastCrawlDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCrawlUrls_cl_LastCrawlDate]  DEFAULT ('2000-08-11 15:18:47.407'),
    [cl_CrawlSource] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCrawlUrls_cl_CrawlSource]  DEFAULT ('null'),
    [cl_CrawlOrgUrl] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCrawlUrls_cl_CrawlOrgUrl]  DEFAULT ('null'),
    [cl_ExploredURL] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCrawlUrls_cl_ExploredURL]  DEFAULT ('null'),
    [cl_Ignored_By_Containing_Word] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCrawlUrls_cl_Ignored_By_Containing_Word]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [cl_CrawlFailedTimes] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCrawlUrls_cl_CrawlFailedTimes]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [cl_TotalCrawlTimes] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCrawlUrls_cl_TotalCrawlTimes]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [cl_UpdatedTimes] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCrawlUrls_cl_UpdatedTimes]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [cl_DuplicateUrl_ByCanonical] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCrawlUrls_cl_DuplicateUrl_ByCanonical]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [cl_PageProcessed] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCrawlUrls_cl_PageProcessed]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [cl_LastProcessDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCrawlUrls_cl_LastProcessDate]  DEFAULT ('2000-08-11 15:18:47.407'),
    [cl_PossibleProductPage] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCrawlUrls_cl_PossibleProductPage]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [cl_CertainlyNotProductPage] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCrawlUrls_cl_CertainlyNotProductPage]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [cl_IsProductPage] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCrawlUrls_cl_IsProductPage]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [cl_Determined_Not_A_Product_Page] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCrawlUrls_cl_NotProduct_Page]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [cl_FreeCargo] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCrawlUrls_cl_FreeCargo]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [cl_ProductPrice_TL] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCrawlUrls_cl_ProductPrice]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [cl_ProductCode] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [cl_ProductImageLink] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [cl_ProductIdCode] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [cl_ProductCategoriesAsText] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [cl_ProductDetailedExplanation] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [cl_ProductFeatures_Wrapped] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblCrawlUrls] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [cl_IdUrl] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblRootSites](
    [cl_RootSiteId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [cl_SiteRootUrl] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [cl_Disabled] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblRootSites_Disabled]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [cl_AlexaRank_TR] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblRootSites_cl_AlexaRank]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [cl_RegisterTime] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblRootSites_cl_RegisterTime]  DEFAULT (sysutcdatetime()),
    [cl_PriceDelimeter] [varchar](1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblRootSites_cl_PriceDelimeter]  DEFAULT ('.'),
    [cl_PriceIgnoreDelimeter] [varchar](1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblRootSites_cl_PriceIgnoreDelimeter]  DEFAULT (','),
    [cl_CertainProductPageDefiner] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblRootSites_cl_CertainProductPageDefiner]  DEFAULT ('null'),
    [cl_ProductCategoryListing_Priority] [smallint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblRootSites_cl_ProductCategoryListing_Priority]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [cl_Ignore_Words_From_Category] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblRootSites_cl_Ignore_From_Category]  DEFAULT ('null'),
    [cl_Ignore_Words_From_Urls] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblRootSites_cl_Ignore_Urls_Parameters]  DEFAULT ('null'),
    [cl_Use_Last_Category_As_A_Product_Code] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblRootSites_cl_Use_Last_Category_As_A_Product_Code]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [cl_Use_Custom_Character_Encoding] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblRootSites_cl_Use_Custom_Character_Encoding]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [cl_IgnorePages_Words] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblRootSites_cl_IgnorePages_Words]  DEFAULT ('null'),
    [cl_IgnoreLastCategory] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tblRootSites_cl_IgnoreLastCategory]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblRootSites] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [cl_RootSiteId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is my SQL query:

```
 SELECT TOP 1000 cl_idurl,
                cl_roositeid,
                cl_crawlsource,
                cl_crawlorgurl
FROM   tblcrawlurls
WHERE  cl_pageprocessed = 0
       AND cl_totalcrawltimes > 0
       AND cl_certainlynotproductpage = 0
       AND cl_duplicateurl_bycanonical = 0
       AND cl_roositeid IN (SELECT cl_rootsiteid
                            FROM   tblrootsites
                            WHERE  cl_disabled = 0)
ORDER  BY cl_lastprocessdate ASC
```

Here is the index which I assumed would be used, but it is not being used.

```
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [TCT-PP-LPD-CNPP-DUBC] ON [dbo].[tblCrawlUrls]
(
    [cl_TotalCrawlTimes] ASC,
    [cl_PageProcessed] ASC,
    [cl_LastProcessDate] ASC,
    [cl_CertainlyNotProductPage] ASC,
    [cl_DuplicateUrl_ByCanonical] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [cl_IdUrl],
    [cl_RooSiteId],
    [cl_CrawlOrgUrl]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85)
```

In my query I use these as restrictions (in the where clause)

```
cl_pageprocessed
cl_totalcrawltimes
cl_certainlynotproductpage
cl_duplicateurl_bycanonical
```

I am assuming that using an index that includes these columns to determine possible primary key ids should be faster than total clustered index scan. But SQL Server is not doing that.

So my logic is not correct and that is what I want to learn. Why does SQL Server choose not to use my index? Not using my index means extra unnecessary load on my database and my hard drives.

Here is the execution plan:

[image]

Comment: Not sure about sql server but you might gain some speed by replacing the subquery with a JOIN.

Comment: A seek is not always better than a scan. See [this post](https://lobsterpot.com.au/blog/2014/03/12/scans-are-better-than-seeks-really/) and [#2 here](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-56-sql-server-assumptions). Feel free to force a seek in this case - if it's even possible, due to the issues brought up below, you can compare the plans and it should be clear why SQL Server chose a scan instead (remember that lookups are expensive and seeks - on non-covering indexes - are usually only good for a small percentage of the table).

Answer (score 5):

Your first column in the index is cl_totalcrawltimes.
In the WHERE clause you're using this column to define a lower range (cl_totalcrawltimes > 0).

Depending on the data distribution this most probably will lead to an index scan instead of an index seek.
Furthermore, cl_crawlsource is not part of the index (the include section, preferrably), so this would require a clustered index key lookup anyway.

Therefore, SQL Server ignores the index since it seems to be more efficient to perform a clustered index scan.

For best results, make those columns on which you query for an exact match the first columns of your nonclustered index. (Whether the next column should be your inequality column or your order by column depends on what the optimizer likes, if any.)

Comment: The order of indexes changes things ? Never think of that. Also if i made it != 0 would it change seek instead of scan ? crawlsource is nvarchar max so i am not willing to add it to the index. aren't there anyway to improve orderby query ?

Comment: Equality operators should always come first in an index definition.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG If you're not willing to add crawlsource to the index (as an INCLUDE column) then you have to understand the trade-off you're making, even if it is the right one: it means that SQL Server will always have to pull that data from a different index, so even if you do manage to coerce a seek in some cases, it's going to need a key lookup to pull that column at least from the clustered index. (My analogy: key lookups are a seek's kryptonite, and are usually a big part of convincing SQL Server to switch to a scan.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes that is something i accept however my logic is incorrect somehow. It comes to me faster to look index for certain predicates instead of scanning entire clustered index however sql server is not making it. So i am trying to understand reason :D I deleted indexes and analyzing 2 GB tuning trace file to see what suggestions will make database engine tuning advisor.

Comment: If you don't want to include crawlsource as an included column, chances are high that SQL Server will ignore the index. Let's assume the query estimates to return 1000 rows. This would imply 1000 lookups. So, why not use the clustered index in the first place? (the logic to decide whether an index is used or not is "slightly" more complex though....). Try to run the query with your index in place (including the changed order of columns) and run it with and without the crawlsource column in the select part. I'm confident SQL Sever will use the index in one scenario...

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG You also have to take into account how an index is structured... more selective columns should be first, because that helps SQL Server eliminate a lot of pages right out of the gate. If you lead with a column with very common values (most notorious is BIT), SQL Server still has to look at a lot of data to find the ones in there that contain the data that matches the more selective predicates that are further down the index key. Think about a phone book - imagine if it was ordered by street name, and then age, and then last name? Good luck finding your buddy John Smith now.

Comment: @AaronBertrand i see. so if not all columns are not in the index it is highly possible sql server will ignore it. I am still waiting database engine tuning advisor to finish its process.